# Is it possible to use a single image sensor to capture a stereoscopic image?

Tags: camera-design, 3d, stereoscopy

I was wondering if there is a way of splitting  a digital image sensor's surface in two and using it to capture a stereo version of an image, maybe using some clever optical system with mirrors (like a periscope... actually, two of them) or something. I want to reproduce that information as 3D on a screen.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.
Do you want to modify a camera? Or do you ask if theoretically something like that could be produced?

Comment: More like theoretically... if the idea is good enogh, I'd like to try it. I'm just courious if something like actually capturing 2 different angle images with the same sensor is possible.

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous products available which do this exact thing.  They are adapters which often fit over an existing lens to produce 2 images on the sensor.

A quick search on `3d lens` will give you the most hits though it isn't something I'd consider an obvious search term.

Products I'm aware of include ranges from [Loreo](http://www.loreo.com/) and [Kula 3d](http://www.kula3d.com/).  There is/was a 3d lens made by Canon but that was for video and I couldn't find a current page on their website (will update if I locate it).

Also you might be interested in the [Samsung NX300 and 45mm 3d lens](http://www.dpreview.com/articles/6733682478/samsung-announces-price-and-availability-of-nx300-and-45mm-f1p8-lens) which uses a novel internal LCD to black out half the lens across 2 exposures to provide separate images to the sensor.